# Certificate is not an RSA certificate when calling FromSigningCredentials for custom Azure B2C Invitation Policy

Tags: certificate, rsa, azure-ad-b2c, sample, x509certificate2

I'm trying this custom invitation policy code for Azure B2C:

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite#signup-with-email-invitation

I followed the step by step guide and created the certificate but when the code hits the method `FromSigningCredentials` it throws the exception `Certificate is not an RSA certificate.`.

Here's [the code](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/44eaa3be99c22541d71465d9a592078be6de95a6/policies/invite/source-code/AADB2C.Invite/Models/JwksModel.cs#L46):

```cs
public static JwksKeyModel FromSigningCredentials(X509SigningCredentials signingCredentials)
{
    X509Certificate2 certificate = signingCredentials.Certificate;

    // JWK cert data must be base64 (not base64url) encoded
    string certData = Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert));

    // JWK thumbprints must be base64url encoded (no padding or special chars)
    string thumbprint = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(certificate.GetCertHash());

    // JWK must have the modulus and exponent explicitly defined
    RSACng rsa = certificate.PublicKey.Key as RSACng;

    if (rsa == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Certificate is not an RSA certificate.");
    }

    .
    .
    .
```

The certificate is loaded but after executing the line:

```cs
RSACng rsa = certificate.PublicKey.Key as RSACng;
```

`rsa` is null.

[image]

This happens locally and on Azure web site.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I just found the following issue @ GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26682

User **bartonjs** [tells the following](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26682#issuecomment-361752540):

> No one should ever call cert.PublicKey.Key; you should instead use
>   cert.GetRSAPublicKey().

I replaced that line in my question with:

```
// JWK must have the modulus and exponent explicitly defined
RSACng rsa = certificate.GetRSAPublicKey() as RSACng;
```

Now I'm good to go...

Comment: Ideally you'd just use `RSA`, not `RSACng`, since `RSACng` only works on Windows.... and then you don't need an `as` operator, since `GetRSAPublicKey()` returns an `RSA` instance.

Comment: @bartonjs thank you! this comment saved me what would probably have been hours of trying to figure out why it worked locally but not deployed.